# Leaflet.js marker popup opens only on first click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have set up a click handler for each marker, that checks if the the marker has a popup set, sets it if not and then opens the popup.

The popup will only open on the first click for every marker. The click is still being registered but the .openPopup() function is not opening the popup.

```
marker.on('click', function() {
                if(!this.getPopup()) {
                    this.bindPopup('<p>Test</p>');
                }

                this.openPopup();
            });
```

Comment: How do you close the popup?

Comment: either by clicking on the map (outside the popup) or using the close button inside the popup. I found a temporary solution to the problem, by not appending the popup to the marker, but instead to the map itself.